# strange behavior when creating array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
 if(ssnFlag == false){
                console.log(userName)
                userSessions.push({userName : [{"sessionId" : dsid}]})
                console.log("pushing::" + JSON.stringify(userSessions[0]))
              }
```

the output is

```
OIC_PLAN_ADMIN_OPERATIONS
pushing::{"userName":[{"sessionId":"0000MTEJon9Fs1MLIMK6yf1Ry1Ob0004vf"}]}
```

Notice when userName value is OIC_PLAN_ADMIN_OPERATIONS then why in the next like the word userName is being pushed when i am expecting it to push OIC_PLAN_ADMIN_OPERATIONS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add some brackets to turn it into a ["Computed property name"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
  { [userName]: /*...*/ }
```

If you omit them, it is the same as:

```
 { "userName": /*...*/ }
```

Comment: What is this use of square braces called?  I've never seen them used in an object key like this.

Comment: Disregard, I found it.  It was easier to Google than I expected.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names